# How to integrate to solve a PDE with mixed partials in the integrand

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, proof-verification, partial-derivative, heat-equation

> Problem Statement: Determine the equlibrium temperature distribution inside a circular annulus $r_1\leq r \leq r_2$. If the outer radius is at temperature $T_2$ and inner radius at temp $T_1$.

So my teacher told us to use the formula $\Delta u=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r \frac{du}{dr})$ and solve the equation $$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r \frac{du}{dr})=0$$
So I have $$\int \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r \frac{du}{dr})dr=\int 0\ dr$$ which i tried applying integration by parts on with $$a=\frac{1}{r},\ da = \ln r\ dr,\ dv =\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r \frac{du}{dr})dr,\ v=r \frac{du}{dr}$$

So then I get $$\frac{du}{dr}-\int r\ln r \frac{du}{dr}dr=\int 0\ dr$$

Here is where I think I messed up (if I hadn't already made a mistake). I thought it would transform to:
$$\frac{du}{dr}-\int r\ln r\ du=\int 0\ dr$$

resulting in:

$$\frac{du}{dr}-r\ln r\ u=C$$

I thought this was a linear equation with $$\mu (r)=e^{-\int r\ln r dr}=e^{-r^2(\frac{1}{2}\ln r-\frac{1}{4})}=r^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}e^{\frac{1}{4}r^2}$$
This left me with:
$$e^{-r^2(\frac{1}{2}\ln r-\frac{1}{4})}u=C\int e^{-r^2(\frac{1}{2}\ln r-\frac{1}{4})}dr$$

but this is way to complicated to solve with elementary functions.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You applied integration by parts incorrectly..

$$a = \frac{1}{r} \implies da = \frac{-1}{r^{2}} dr \ne da = \ln (r) dr$$

Comment: lol! wow of course basic Calculus was my problem. but I should still apply integration by parts to solve that integral, yes?

Comment: Yes, but you don't get the result you thought it would transform to. After an application of IBP I get

$$\int \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \bigg( r \frac{du}{dr} \bigg) dr = \frac{du}{dr} + \int \frac{1}{r} \frac{du}{dr}$$

Comment: So much simpler! Thank you for pointing that out! :)

Comment: All good mate. In your original equation, you should probably have just multiplied through by $r$ first too.